# Android Studio record Espresso test - unable to handle Google Login window

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso-recorder

Android Studio Stable 2.3.2.I want to record Espresso test to be able to test login with Google account. Login is implemented with Firebase, when user choose to login, popup to select phone Google account appears and user needs to select account.

My problem is when recording Espresso test, it can't see popup dialog to select account as test step, so I am unable to add ViewInteraction to automatically choose Google account and my resulting test will not perform Google login. Similar issue with PlacePicker and any intent not belong to my app.

Is there any solution to force Espresso recording to handle that?

Comment: Espresso has its problems. It might not be able to do that. I know ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 doesn't work that way either last time I used it. And I don't think Google cares really all that much as their own apps and AS itself has tons of bugs.

Comment: Can I manage to add it manually somehow?